# Find g''(x) where g is a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

$$g(x) = \int_0^x\left(\int_0^{sin(y)} \sqrt{z^{10}+1} \;dz\right)dy$$

$g'(x) =\int_0^{sin(x)}\sqrt{z^{10}+1} \;dz$

$g''(x) = cos(x)\sqrt{sin^{10}(x) + 1} \;$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Well done!

Comment: If the outer integral's upper-bound changed to $x^2$ would it be:

$g'(x) = 2x\;\int_0^{sin(x^2)}\sqrt{z^{10}+1}\;dz$


 
$g''(x) = (2x)(2xcos(x^2))\sqrt{sin^{10}(x^2) + 1}$ ?

Comment: Almost. You need to use the product rule in that second step, no?

Comment: Ah, you're right, so it'll be something like $2\int_0^{sin(x^2)}\sqrt{z^{10}+1}\;dz + (2x)(2xcos(x^2))\sqrt{sin^{10}(x^2) + 1}$

Comment: That looks correct.